# I'm getting an error message in Java when I'm trying to sort arrays, but most of my code make sense to me

Tags: java

I get this error message,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
    at OrganizATION.main(OrganizATION.java:31)
```

and I understand that it's something with my printing command. Here is my code.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class OrganizATION {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int[] aryNums;
    aryNums = new int[6];

    aryNums[0] = 8;
    aryNums[1] = 7;
    aryNums[2] = 89;
    aryNums[3] = 823;
    aryNums[4] = 45;
    aryNums[5] = 60;

    Arrays.sort(aryNums);;

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < aryNums.length; i++);

    System.out.println("Number: " + aryNums[i]);

    }
}
```

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < aryNums.length; i++);` - lose the`;`

Comment: remove ; after your if statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
Arrays.sort(aryNums);;

int i;

for (i = 0; i < aryNums.length; i++);

System.out.println("Number: " + aryNums[i]);
```

1. `Arrays.sort(aryNums);;`

Delete one trailing semi-colon.

2. `for (i = 0; i < aryNums.length; i++);`

Also, delete the trailing semi colon. Because all what this loop does "as is", is to increment the `i` variable **6 times**. Causing the line after

```
System.out.println("Number: " + aryNums[i]); // aryNums[6] : invalid
```

to throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two semi-colons in this line:

```
Arrays.sort(aryNums);;
```

And one after this if

```
for (i = 0; i < aryNums.length; i++); //<this semi-colon
System.out.println("Number: " + aryNums[i]);
```

Extra semi-colons or missing ones can make your code not work.

Remove those and you will be fine.